# Problem with read command while searching txt file line by line

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, read

I am trying to do a simple dictionary of words inserted by user which are collected in txt file and then the function to learn them. Words in two different languages are seperated by a chosen seperator and then checked if the answer typed by user is correct. I've had a problem with the txt file lines being skipped after first iteration so I used a subshell, which works fine, if I didn't have a variables counting correct/wrong answers in it. I don't really know how to solve this.
My piece of code:

```
count=0
ans=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    (...)
    (                     # without subshell the lines from txt file were skipped
    exec 0< /dev/tty      # I used this command to prevent skipping the "read check" line 
                          # as it happened before 
    read check
    if [ "$check" == "$correct" ];then
        echo "Correct"
        let ans++
        let count++
    else
        echo "Wrong"
        let count++
    fi
    )
done < "file.txt"
echo "Answered $ans out of $count words correctly"
```

Comment: The `read` can be confused, when the file you read is simultaneously updated.

Comment: The redirection `< "file.txt"` outside the loop sets the stdin of the whole loop. `exec 0< /dev/tty` would set stdin again, overriding the redirection. If you put the `exec` in a subshell, the redirection there only applies to the subshell.

Comment: You might want to put the redirection of the file in some other fd, e.g. `while IFS= read -r <&3; do ... done 3< file.txt`

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks it it worked just fine